# How to get the active strips in the NLA editor from Python?

Tags: python, nla-editor

Is it possible to get the active strips in the *NLA Editor* with Python, in order to run a function on them?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the active NLA track, but the strips array has no property `.active` in the Python API. It's not exposed, but the active strip is known in the C code (note that the 
*Active Strip* panel is hardcoded).

All you can do with Python is to get all *selected* strips:

```
try:
    selected_strips = [strip for strip in bpy.context.object.animation_data.nla_tracks.active.strips if strip.select]
except AttributeError:
    selected_strips = []
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is as I thought when I looked the source. Too bad for my addon.

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy

for i in bpy.data.objects:
    for j in i.animation_data.nla_tracks.values():
        for k in j.strips.values():
            if k.active:
                print(k)
```

Comment: Your code seems to give the _selected_ strips, not the _active_ strips.

Comment: Yes. I use select instead active